# how to know if a directory is referenced by a symlink

Tags: shell, command-line, ubuntu, symbolic-link

Is there a command that I could execute to find out if a directory is referenced by a symlink somewhere on the machine.

ie:

```
pwd =>  /home/user/source/

vdir 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user group   24 2011-04-08 10:59 Symlink -> /home/user/source/Test
drwxr-xr-x 2 user group 4096 2011-04-08 10:59 Test
```

Using this exemple, I want to know where to find Symlink because it reference Test.

I use Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try something like:

```
sudo find / -lname /path/to/your/file
```

But beware that some links can be defined with relative paths.

Or you can list all symbolic links and grep for your file using:

```
sudo find / -type l | grep /path/to/your/file
```

(the "l" in "-type l" is not the number one but L)

But each method has some drawbacks. Maybe someone knows better?

Answer (score 1):

You have to scan the entire filesystem for softlinks, then resolve them and see if they point to the same location.  Don't try to do a text-compare of the link destination, since that could go through another hard or softlink; you need to compare inodes probably.

Comment: @jesup, Do you have any example of commands, to do this. I am starting to discover the benefits of the command line. thanks

Comment: I'd start with 'find -L / -xtype l -samefile Test'  That may do it right there

Comment: I'd start with 'find -L / -xtype l -samefile Test' ---  That may do it right there (find is powerful).  I was going to get a list of all links with 'find / -type l' and pipe it to xargs to test against the inode number of Test, but the first version seems to do it all.

Comment: @jesup, `find -L / -xtype l -samefile Test` works perfectly thanks. But I had to call it with `sudo`.